# Need a macro to copy specific cells from a row in one worksheet to a specific cells in another worksheet base upon a data in the cell

Tags: vba, excel, cells

I am working on a workbook for my business.

[image: Trip Logs]

Would like to get a Macro going to copy data from a few cells in a row (cell through  C to G) of one worksheet to another worksheet row (cells A,B,C,F,G).

The catch is, they need to be only transferred if D column has data entered.

[image: Driver Reimbursement]

I'm unable to properly use code that Alex P wrote for a somewhat similar problem:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim nextRow As Long
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D:D")) Is Nothing Then
        If VBA.IsDate(Target) Then
            With Worksheets("Sheet2")
                nextRow = IIf(VBA.IsEmpty(.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp)), 1, .Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row + 1)
                .Range("A" & nextRow) = Target.Offset(0, -3)
                .Range("B" & nextRow) = Target.Offset(0, -1)
                .Range("C" & nextRow) = Target
            End With
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: "can't make it work correct" is somewhat vague. What is the actual problem?

Comment: Thanks a lot to editors for making it much more presentable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. I got this worksheet:
[image: Sheet 1] 
sheet1

[image: sheet 2]
sheet 2

Applying the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim nextRow As Long
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D:D")) Is Nothing Then
    If Not VBA.IsEmpty(Target) Or VBA.IsNull(Target) Then
        With Worksheets("Sheet2")
            nextRow = IIf(VBA.IsEmpty(.Range("B1048576").End(xlUp)), 1, .Range("B1048576").End(xlUp).Row + 1)
            .Range("A" & nextRow) = Target.Offset(0, -1)
            .Range("B" & nextRow) = Target
            .Range("C" & nextRow) = Target.Offset(0, 1)
            .Range("F" & nextRow) = Target.Offset(0, 2)
            .Range("G" & nextRow) = Target.Offset(0, 3)
        End With
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Try enter new line at sheet 1
[image]

Result at sheet 2
[image]

Something you need take note is : make sure column D at sheet 1 is the last item to be entered, if you enter it first, and empty row will be copied.

Comment: It works, but puts it under my "total" row.  Also if I change the target range to column G, I can input data in order?

Comment: Sorry, I did not get what you trying to mean. Are you going to put the Sheet1's column H to sheet 2's column H? If you would like to do it, you need use this line of code : `.Range("H" & nextRow) = Target.Offset(0, 4)` Yes that you can change the target range to column G to input orderly, just that you need to do modification in the code. The offset value need to be changed as you need point to the left, it will be negative values.

Comment: I mean the code works, it just copies the row under the row "Total" on my worksheet "Driver Reimbursement"  [IMG]http://i1237.photobucket.com/albums/ff463/tserberis/376373_758927226971_2141590458_n.gif[/IMG]

Comment: I edit my answer, change the line `nextRow = IIf(VBA.IsEmpty(.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp)), 1, .Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row + 1)` from `A` to `B` as column A last row was 14 due to the 'Total' word at the bottom.

Comment: Now there is only one problem, when I try to use my button assigned macro for inserting row with formulas it gives me run time error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: You can user the `Record Marco` feature in Excel and perform the work manually to create the script behind. After that, modified the recorded script to fulfill your need